# Invoking OFBIZ web service using Apache CXF or JAX-WS

Tags: soap, wsdl, cxf, mule, ofbiz

I have an OFBiz SOAP-based web service that is exposed (can accept requests) and has a WSDL code generated and a WSDL URL. My Question is, is there a way to consume this web service using a CXF Java client or JAX-WS client?

Overall, i want to be able to add the client in the Mule esb consigeration as part of a Mule FLOW. I can invoke the OFBiz web service using AXIS2, but Mule ESB does not seem to support AXIS2, which brings me to another question - Is there a way i can configure AXIS2 web service client in Mule ESB?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Follow the WSDL-first approach from the [Consuming Web Services](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF) user guide.

This involves:

- generating a CXF client using the WSDL to Java tool from CXF or the Maven plugin,
- configuring the client as an outbound endpoint.

And leads to a Mule configuration that looks like:

```
<cxf:jaxws-client
     clientClass="org.apache.hello_world_soap_http.SOAPService"
     wsdlPort="SoapPort"
     wsdlLocation="classpath:/wsdl/hello_world.wsdl"
     operation="greetMe"/>
<outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:63081/services/greeter"/>
```